# Layout in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am new to UIScrollView, and they are driving me crazy.

I am trying to create a screen that has a title and some descriptive text at the top, and then a scroll view (with paging enabled) in the bottom two thirds of the screen. This scroll view will contain 1-3 images. Ideally, I'd like the first image to appear centered in the initial scroll view window, and then enable the user to view the other images by scrolling/paging horizontally, again ideally with each image centered in its 'page'.

The code below loads the images for 'item' from the Internet, creates a UIImageView for each, and inserts them into the scroll view. According to the frame calculations, I would expect the first image to be up against the left side of the scrollview, and then the other images to the right, with no space between them. But instead, the first image is shifted to the right, about half-way across the screen, and there are equally large spaces between each image.

I have turned off paging to simplify matters, and I have tried experimenting with tweaking the image frame values, trying to understand what's happening, but nothing works as I expect it to.

I am guessing that autolayout is messing with me. Can someone confirm that, and maybe give me some hints on how to get this scrollview under control?

Thanks in advance.

```
self.imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.imageScrollView.frame.size.width * (imageFieldNames.count),
                                              self.imageScrollView.frame.size.height);
self.imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;

CGFloat xPos = 0.0;

for (NSString *field in imageFieldNames) {
    NSString *name = [self.item valueForKey:field];
    if (name.length > 0) {
        UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self loadImage:iv withFile:name];

        iv.frame = CGRectMake(xPos, 0.0,
                              self.imageScrollView.frame.size.width,
                              self.imageScrollView.frame.size.height);
        [self.imageScrollView addSubview:iv];
        xPos += self.imageScrollView.frame.size.width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `UIPageViewController` instead of a scrollview?

Comment: I looked at it, but I don't want to page the text at the top of the screen. If I could insert a UIPageView in the view, to just replace the UIScrollView, that would be perfect... I wonder if that is possible?

Comment: Through the magic of View Controller Containment, it is possible. You could even easily do it with the storyboard.

Comment: Ah... Okay! I just found the container in IB. That might do the trick. I still wonder why its so difficult to arrange things in a scrollview, though. It seems to make using them very hard. However, I am going to try the page view for now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: At what point in your view controller's lifecycle is the provided code executed? My hunch is prior to auto layout doing its final pass. You should add your subview then update their frames in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: The code above is in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Wow, doing the layout in viewDidLayoutSubviews was the trick! I wish I could mark that as the right answer! Thank you very much!